# Wrap div below absolute positioned div in fluid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fluid image rotator that scales with the browser. I have to have the images inside the rotator set to absolute but this affects the layout with the 'body-content' falling behind the image. If the images are set to relative then the image rotator doesn't work. I've been looking at this all day does anyone have any ideas? Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main-image">
  <div id="rotator">
    <img src="image1.jpg" border="0" alt=""/>
    <img src="image2.jpg" border="0" alt="" /> 
    <img src="image3.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="body-content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-image {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#main-image IMG.active {
  z-index:10;
}
#main-image IMG.last-active {
  z-index:9;
}
#rotator {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position:relative;
}
#rotator img{
  position: absolute;    
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#body-content {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fatfrank44/Q7vpD/8/

Thanks

Comment: is this what your after? http://jsfiddle.net/Q7vpD/9/

Comment: Thanks but I want the 'body-content' div to appear below the slideshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7vpD/10/) All I did is set the height of `#main-image` to the height of the images inside of it, so that the body-content div is pushed down.

```
$('#main-image').height($('#rotator img:first').height());
```

[Fiddle with window resize and working slider](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7vpD/17/)

Comment: Hi Watson, thank you, this is so very near. However, when I resize the window the 'body-content' needs to move up with the scaled image, it's currently fixed.

Comment: I would put the code in my answer in a re-size function which fires every time the window is resized -- have added fiddle to answer.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you so much - I've spent hours on this today and I was going round in circles! Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Any idea why the image rotator isn't working now though, I notice the bottom part is commented out?

Comment: That works but only makes the 'body-content' move below after the first image transition. Is this something to do with window.load?

Comment: Thanks Watson, that sorted it!!

Comment: So, did I answer your question?